# How to compile Makefile based recipe in bitbake?

Tags: makefile, yocto

I am trying to create a recipe in yocto to build a package for SDK - https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser

Here is my http-parser.bb. However, when I am trying to build using - "-c populate_sdk", I get the error that no Makefile found.
What am I missing here? My source code has Makefile. I am following the book by Rudolf - Yocto book and I can't see anything except adding the following from chapter 8 - Software package recipe.

```
do_install() {
oe_runmake install PREFIX=${D}
}
```

Here is my recipe file.

```
SUMMARY = "http-parser"
DESCRIPTION = "This is a parser for HTTP messages written in C. It parses both requests and responses. The parser is designed to be used in performance HTTP applications. It does not make any syscalls nor allocations, it does not buffer data, it can be interrupted at anytime. Depending on your architecture, it only requires about 40 bytes of data per message stream (in a web server that is per connection)."

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE-MIT;md5=9bfa835d048c194ab30487af8d7b3778"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "59f8fce33369f2ef2a45f46b6b5420bc"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "865e0ec42f3c0a949654ebff98d538dd828a239392b502d42e15cb1e5bb28895"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
PV = "r${SRCREV}"
PR = "r2"

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser.git"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"


PARALLEL_MAKE = ""
```

After running bitbake, I get an error no Makefile found.

Comment: So the code is using a Makefile, but why do you inherrit autotools-*?.  This is when havingg configure, makefile.am, ...
@see: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-base

Comment: Yes, it is using makefile. I find these manuals quite difficult to follow. There are no examples and guidelines. These manuals are like dictionary and there is no way to know when and how to apply because they lack examples and guidelines.

Comment: I have updated the post now with more details like what I have tried so far and what is the problem.

Comment: Hi,  The mega manual of Yocto is IMHO still the best technical documentation I ever have seen.  But if I you are looking for example, just do a grep on 'oe_runmake' in the source directory of your yocto project.